# How to include onsen using requirejs?

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

I'm trying to test my app built using onsen-ui. We're using requirejs to load up onsen amongst other scripts. However, running our tests results in the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined
```

This is the relevant part where scripts are loaded

```
  require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base/www/js',

  // example of using shim, to load non AMD libraries (such as underscore and jquery)
  paths: {
    angular:          '../bower_components/angular/angular',
    angularResource:  '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource',
    angularMocks:     '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
    onsenui:          '../bower_components/onsenui/build/js/onsenui',
    stateMachine:     '../bower_components/javascript-state-machine/state-machine',
    ngRaven:          '../bower_components/angular-raven/angular-raven',
    underscore:       '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
    moment:           '../bower_components/momentjs/moment',
    xml2json:         '../bower_components/x2js/xml2json'
  },
  shim: {
    angular: {
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    angularMocks: {
      exports: 'angular.mock',
      deps: ['angular']
    },
    ngRaven: ['angular'],
    angularResource: ['angular'],
    onsenui: {
      exports: 'onsen',
      deps: ['angular']
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    xml2json : {
      exports : 'X2JS'
    }
  },

  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: tests,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Comment: Figure out how the other things are defined, then copy that method.

Comment: I think the problem is that onsen has hardcoded an old version of hammerjs directly into its script. It's a little confusing as to how Hammer should be defined

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a reference to the script in the file that you're using the script in?